# webrtc android video call sound has screeching sound and echos

Tags: android, webrtc, voip, opus

I am trying to implement VideoCall feature using [this repo](https://github.com/vivek1794/webrtc-android-codelab/tree/master/Step-3) as base. I got everything working but now the issue is the audio is very poor and it has screeching sound and echo. Audio is barely audible. I am using proper constraints when creating audio source in both callee/caller. Here is how I create audio source-

```
    MediaConstraints audioConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
    audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googNoiseSuppression", "true"));
    audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("googEchoCancellation", "true"));
    audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("echoCancellation", "true"));
    audioConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("noiseSuppression", "true"));
    AudioSource audioSource = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioSource(audioConstraints);
    localAudioTrack = peerConnectionFactory.createAudioTrack("101", audioSource);
```

Please help me get this working.

Comment: I tried changing codec/bitrates but problem remains same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was when enabling remote audio track I had these lines set

```
AudioTrack audioTrack = mediaStream.audioTracks.get(0);
audioTrack.setEnabled(true);
audioTrack.setVolume(100); // culprit
```

The last line where I set volume to 100 was the issue. Removing it did the trick.